# What's the difference between deactivating and disabling a breakpoint in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome (Version 23.0.1271.101). I'm on OS X, if that even matters.

Why does Chrome have the ability to disable and/or deactivate breakpoints? Is there some power use I am not aware of?

I *have* noticed that I can disable some breakpoints, then deactivate all. Upon reactivating them, the same disabled ones are disabled. Other than that, what's the purpose of having having the two options?

[image]

Comment: not an answer - but try experimenting with http://chromedevtools.googlecode.com/svn-history/r421/trunk/tutorials/breapoints/index.html .. you might be able to find this answer yourself

Comment: Presumably because deactivated ones could be later re-activated while deleted ones are gone, no?

Comment: Ignore the highlighted 'remove' action. I'm talking about, for example, "Deactivate All Breakpoints" vs "Disable All Breakpoints".

Comment: At least a few months ago, disabled breakpoints could still slow down the JS considerably whereas deactivated breakpoints had no JS overhead. This is a bug though and may have already been addressed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Deactivate Breakpoints turns off the breakpoint functionality.  Disable All Breakpoints is a shortcut for marking each breakpoint as disabled.

The difference becomes clearer when you compare Enable All Breakpoints and Activate Breakpoints.

Individual breakpoints can be enabled or disabled through the checkboxes next to each breakpoint.

[image]

Disable All Breakpoints unchecks all breakpoints, in effect turning off breakpoint functionality.  Deactivate Breakpoints explicitly turns off breakpoint functionality.  So these two options have the same effect.

Activate Breakpoints enables breakpoint functionality, preserving the individual breakpoints' enabled/disabled status.  Enable All Breakpoints enables each breakpoint, but doesn't turn breakpoint functionality itself on if it has been deactivated.

Comment: Deactivate also turns off breaking at `debugger` statements. That is not possible with "disable all".

Answer (score 1):

This is the breakpoint prototype from the recent chromium sources. As you can see a breakpoint is enabled or disabled. I dont see any property that could reflect a breakpoint being either "disabled" or "deactivated". Maybe it has something to do with conditions. Otherwise I would say it is a frontend inconsistency.

```
WebInspector.BreakpointManager.Breakpoint.prototype = {
/**
 * @return {WebInspector.UILocation}
 */
primaryUILocation: function()
{
    return this._primaryUILocation;
},

/**
 * @param {WebInspector.DebuggerModel.Location} location
 */
_addResolvedLocation: function(location)
{
    this._liveLocations.push(this._breakpointManager._debuggerModel.createLiveLocation(location, this._locationUpdated.bind(this, location)));
},

/**
 * @param {WebInspector.DebuggerModel.Location} location
 * @param {WebInspector.UILocation} uiLocation
 */
_locationUpdated: function(location, uiLocation)
{
    var stringifiedLocation = location.scriptId + ":" + location.lineNumber + ":" + location.columnNumber;
    var oldUILocation = /** @type {WebInspector.UILocation} */ (this._uiLocations[stringifiedLocation]);
    if (oldUILocation)
        this._breakpointManager._uiLocationRemoved(this, oldUILocation);
    if (this._uiLocations[""]) {
        delete this._uiLocations[""];
        this._breakpointManager._uiLocationRemoved(this, this._primaryUILocation);
    }
    this._uiLocations[stringifiedLocation] = uiLocation;
    this._breakpointManager._uiLocationAdded(this, uiLocation);
},

/**
 * @return {boolean}
 */
enabled: function()
{
    return this._enabled;
},

/**
 * @param {boolean} enabled
 */
setEnabled: function(enabled)
{
    this._updateBreakpoint(this._condition, enabled);
},

/**
 * @return {string}
 */
condition: function()
{
    return this._condition;
},

/**
 * @param {string} condition
 */
setCondition: function(condition)
{
    this._updateBreakpoint(condition, this._enabled);
},

/**
 * @param {string} condition
 * @param {boolean} enabled
 */
_updateBreakpoint: function(condition, enabled)
{
    if (this._enabled === enabled && this._condition === condition)
        return;

    if (this._enabled)
        this._removeFromDebugger();

    this._enabled = enabled;
    this._condition = condition;
    this._breakpointManager._storage._updateBreakpoint(this);

    var scriptFile = this._primaryUILocation.uiSourceCode.scriptFile();
    if (this._enabled && !(scriptFile && scriptFile.hasDivergedFromVM())) {
        this._setInDebugger();
        return;
    }

    this._fakeBreakpointAtPrimaryLocation();
},

/**
 * @param {boolean=} keepInStorage
 */
remove: function(keepInStorage)
{
    var removeFromStorage = !keepInStorage;
    this._resetLocations();
    this._removeFromDebugger();
    this._breakpointManager._removeBreakpoint(this, removeFromStorage);
},

_setInDebugger: function()
{
    var rawLocation = this._primaryUILocation.uiLocationToRawLocation();
    var debuggerModelLocation = /** @type {WebInspector.DebuggerModel.Location} */ (rawLocation);
    if (debuggerModelLocation)
        this._breakpointManager._debuggerModel.setBreakpointByScriptLocation(debuggerModelLocation, this._condition, didSetBreakpoint.bind(this));
    else
        this._breakpointManager._debuggerModel.setBreakpointByURL(this._primaryUILocation.uiSourceCode.url, this._primaryUILocation.lineNumber, 0, this._condition, didSetBreakpoint.bind(this));

    /**
     * @this {WebInspector.BreakpointManager.Breakpoint}
     * @param {?DebuggerAgent.BreakpointId} breakpointId
     * @param {Array.<WebInspector.DebuggerModel.Location>} locations
     */
    function didSetBreakpoint(breakpointId, locations)
    {
        if (!breakpointId) {
            this._resetLocations();
            this._breakpointManager._removeBreakpoint(this, false);
            return;
        }

        this._debuggerId = breakpointId;
        this._breakpointManager._breakpointForDebuggerId[breakpointId] = this;

        if (!locations.length) {
            this._fakeBreakpointAtPrimaryLocation();
            return;
        }

        this._resetLocations();
        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; ++i) {
            var script = this._breakpointManager._debuggerModel.scriptForId(locations[i].scriptId);
            var uiLocation = script.rawLocationToUILocation(locations[i].lineNumber, locations[i].columnNumber);
            if (this._breakpointManager.findBreakpoint(uiLocation.uiSourceCode, uiLocation.lineNumber)) {
                // location clash
                this.remove();
                return;
            }
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; ++i)
            this._addResolvedLocation(locations[i]);
    }
},

_removeFromDebugger: function()
{
    if (this._debuggerId) {
        this._breakpointManager._debuggerModel.removeBreakpoint(this._debuggerId);
        delete this._breakpointManager._breakpointForDebuggerId[this._debuggerId];
        delete this._debuggerId;
    }
},

_resetLocations: function()
{
    for (var stringifiedLocation in this._uiLocations)
        this._breakpointManager._uiLocationRemoved(this, this._uiLocations[stringifiedLocation]);

    for (var i = 0; i < this._liveLocations.length; ++i)
        this._liveLocations[i].dispose();
    this._liveLocations = [];

    this._uiLocations = {};
},

/**
 * @return {string}
 */
_breakpointStorageId: function()
{
    return this._sourceFileId + ":" + this._primaryUILocation.lineNumber;
},

_fakeBreakpointAtPrimaryLocation: function()
{
    this._resetLocations();
    this._uiLocations[""] = this._primaryUILocation;
    this._breakpointManager._uiLocationAdded(this, this._primaryUILocation);
}
}
```

Comment: Hm. AFAICT, deactivating is just for turning all your breakpoints off/on while leaving their enabled states intact.